# Showing the amount of results that are returned from a select statement as a column

Tags: sql, ssms

I have written a very simple query to return all departments from my database that have un-commissioned employees, where should i look to now to be able to figure out how to display how many employees there are.

For exmaple i want:

```
Departments | Un-Commissioned Empl.
----------------------------------
Admin.      |         7
Marketing   |         5
Purchasing  |         10
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your model correctly, you need to `join` the 2 tables together, using the `count` aggregate to get the decommissioned employees:

```
select d.department_name, count(*)
from departments d
    inner join employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
where e.commission_pct = 0 
group by d.department_name
```

---

If you need all departments even if they don't have decommissioned employeed, you'll want to use an `outer join` instead and move the where criteria to the join:

```
select d.department_name, count(e.employee_id)
from departments d
    left join employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id 
         and e.commission_pct = 0 
    group by d.department_name
```

Comment: Unfortunately when i try that i get this "Column 'departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: thanks a bunch, now that i know what to do, time to head over to  w3school to learn how to do it.